# ListView Adapter calling getView with the same index 3 times despite there being 17 items in arraylist

Tags: android, xml, listview, adb, listadapter

As the title says, this adapter doesn't work. I've given it an `ArrayList` of `String` arrays. The ArrayList contains 17 `String` arrays. The result should be 17 rows in the List View. Alas, it fails me.

```
@Override
    public View getView(int index, View arg1, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.courses_list, parent, false);
    TextView moduleCode = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.moduleCode);
    moduleCode.setText(list.get(index)[0]);

    Log.i("LIST-GET", Integer.toString(index));

    TextView moduleName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.moduleName);
    moduleName.setText(list.get(index)[1]);

    TextView moduleCredits = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.moduleCredits);
    moduleCredits.setText(list.get(index)[2]);

    CheckBox c = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.moduleCheck);
    c.setChecked(true);

    return view;
}
```

This is what the LogCat outputs:

```
04-29 17:31:13.818  14509-14509/com.example.thing I/LIST-GET﹕ 0
04-29 17:31:13.830  14509-14509/com.example.thing I/LIST-GET﹕ 0
04-29 17:31:13.834  14509-14509/com.example.thing I/LIST-GET﹕ 0
```

This is what the ListView looks like in the XML (with `match_parent` added):

```
<ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/listView"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/yearSpinner"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
```

Whatsagowinown?

EDIT: As requested, the XML that contains the ListView

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        tools:context=".CourseSelection"  >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/title"
            android:textSize="70sp"
            android:textColor="@color/dark_grey"
            android:text="@string/course_select_title"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

        <Spinner
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/departmentSpinner"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/title"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:spinnerMode="dialog" />

        <Spinner
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/courseSpinner"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/departmentSpinner"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:spinnerMode="dialog" />

        <Spinner
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/yearSpinner"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/courseSpinner"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:spinnerMode="dialog" />

        <ListView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/listView"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/yearSpinner"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/listView"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_marginTop="45dp" >

            <GridLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:columnCount="4"
                android:rowCount="2"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" >

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/bCancel"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_column="0"
                    android:layout_row="0"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:background="@drawable/cancel"
                    android:layout_marginRight="34dp" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/bConfirm"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_column="1"
                    android:layout_row="0"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:background="@drawable/signin"/>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tCancel"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_column="0"
                    android:layout_row="1"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:text="@string/cancel"
                    android:layout_marginRight="34dp"
                    android:paddingTop="17dp"/>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tconfirm"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_column="1"
                    android:layout_row="1"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:text="Confirm"
                    android:paddingTop="17dp"
                    android:focusable="false"/>

            </GridLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

EDIT 2: And the XML for the Adapter:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<GridLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:columnCount="2"
    android:id="@+id/courses_list"
    android:background="#FFFFFF"
    android:focusable="false" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/moduleCode"
        android:layout_row="0"
        android:layout_column="1"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|left"
        android:text="XX12345"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#000000" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/moduleName"
        android:layout_row="1"
        android:layout_column="1"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|left"
        android:textColorHighlight="@color/grey"
        android:text="Module name here"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#000000" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="Credits"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|right"
        android:id="@+id/moduleCredits"
        android:layout_row="0"
        android:layout_column="1" />

    <CheckBox
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Taking?"
        android:id="@+id/moduleCheck"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|right"
        android:layout_row="1"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:layout_column="1"
        android:checked="false" />

</GridLayout>
```

Comment: your xml is missing. You might need match_parent on your lsit

Comment: Sorry! I got the wrong view. Both of them started with an L and they're right next to each other!

Comment: I changed it to `match_parent` and it still doesn't work

Comment: Post the full xml, maybe another view is using all space.

Comment: The adapter XML, or the activity XML?

Comment: the one with the listview

Comment: Could you add the full adapter's code?

Comment: Can you also post code for the entire adapter?

Comment: listview inside a scrollview - you're asking for problems dude

Comment: Would that stop the adapter from populating the ListView with rows?

Comment: Okay, turns out that it's actually the scroll view. Can anyone recommend an alternative method?

Comment: Any alternatives found?